# How to pass parameters to Codeigniter controller from view page

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

Hi I need to pass variable parameters to codeigniter controller without click function any link from view page. I have no idea how to pass data to controller from view with out click anything.

My view page name is rows.php, In view page I had variable as below

```
$rows = 10;
```

this rows value I need to send to controller, if I send this to controller will display data as per parameter.

My Controller

```
public function getRows($parameter)
{
after query
$this->load->view('rows',$data);
}
```

I would appreciate your help.

Comment: This variable? yes using scanner. But unfortunately this technology want revealed yet. Til today at least.

Comment: So it is not possible ?

Comment: Without any event you cannot pass parameter to contorller.. But you can with using helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using helper without any clicks.

### Helper

```
 //some_helper
 function abc($b)
 { 
   $a=$b-10;
   return $a;
 }
```

### View

```
 $this->load->helper("some_helper");  //note that helper file name always should be postfixed by '_helper'

 abc(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = "10";

file_get_contents("yoursite.com/getRows/".$rows);
```

or

```
file_get_contents("yoursite.com/index.php/getRows/".$rows);
```

anyway, I don't see why you would like to do so, the view should preferebly not contain your php code but only the html or the variables you want to output.

Comment: Thank you for your help and yes usually it is not recommended but in my work it has happen.